# 403 Forbidden error with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, web-services, http, https

I'm making a web request that redirects user to another URL and fetches the data. In the browser, it redirects properly & returns the result from redirected URL. However, it doesn't work from console application:

```
HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url1);
webrequest.KeepAlive = true;
webrequest.Method = "GET";
webrequest.ContentType = "text/plain";
webrequest.Timeout = 20000;

WebResponse webresponse = webrequest.GetResponse();
Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

string result = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Here the result I get is:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href=\"..........................\">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

So I need to get data from `href` URL of anchor tag.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(result, @"<a\shref=""(?<url>.*?)"">(?<text>.*?)</a>");
Console.WriteLine(matches[0].Groups["url"].Value);

webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(matches[0].Groups["url"].Value);

webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

result = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

But I got a 403: Forbidden error in second request.

With `Fiddler`, response was:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><StringToSignBytes>47 45 54 0a 0a 74 65 78 74 2f 70 6c 61 69 6e 0a 31 33 37 35 38 36 34 31 31 32 0a 2f 61 70 70 74 68 6f 72 69 74 79 2d 73 74 61 74 69 63 2d 72 65 70 6f 72 74 73 2f 36 37 66 62 34 35 39 62 65 63 35 66 63 34 39 37 30 61 32 39 65 64 30 33 61 64 37 30 64 30 31 32 2f 65 6e 2e 6a 73 6f 6e</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>04FB1EFE872CE953</RequestId><HostId>z5KnzkJ2+qzkz1Dad80OPACAvbUbQppLTBRzVp6JiPIIAEWWKi9nckBdXLk5pHzu</HostId><SignatureProvided>kGtsbufDT6eOIDuHnVfDGY20XMA=</SignatureProvided><StringToSign>GET`

Here `Signature` getting sent to second request is the same I've received in `href` URL of first response.

Also, both requests have header `Connection: keep-alive` in browser, but in the console application only the first request has that header (even after `webrequest.KeepAlive = true;`).

Answer (score 0):

try by adding the user agent:

```
request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Rigor/1.0.0; http://rigor.com)";
```